# How to get latest value of an map object globally using react context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have two context variables in my Application 1) data 2) temp, while clicking on button in first component, I am updating those two context variables, but while reading those two variables in second component only 'temp' value is getting updated, 'data' variable is not updating.
here is my executable sandbox repo, please click on button and see the console

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usecontext-forked-dx2vog?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Why don't you make `data` a state like `temp` and pass `setData` to the context? Are there any reasons behind using `data` as a variable, but not a state?

Comment: yes, I need to iterate data in further components and need to modify while iterating(if I make it state variable, while iterating we will not latest updated value), and also I don't want to re-render my components again

Comment: Have `data` also in state.